# Jquery scroll() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery on scroll() to apply z-index to a header on scroll.Please find the UPDATED fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L5pc81r6/2/

As seen the header should remain fixed while scrolling the rest of the body content. However there is something missing that causes my scroll method to fail on scrolling. I had set a debugger at the callback function, but it never goes into that debug point. I wonder whats going on 
js:

```
$("#main").on("scroll",function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                    $('#header').addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                    $('#header').removeClass('fixed');
                }
        });
```

Any ideas are helpful!! Thanks!!

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/): _"The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents)."_ Does your code fit in to any of the mentioned scenarios?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jsfiddle on left sidebar under **Frameworks & Extensions** choose jQuery.

Like this...http://jsfiddle.net/L5pc81r6/4/ using

```
$('#main').on('scroll'...
```

as you were